# Scala - Join dataframes relation 1 to n

Tags: sql, scala, dataframe, apache-spark, one-to-many

I have two dataframes

Dataframe - House(adress, number, zipcode)

```
adress 1, 28, 04030
adress 2, 01, 25040
```

Dataframe - People(name, adress, age)

```
Miki , adress 1, 15
Sterling , adress 2, 20
Archer, adress 2, 25
```

I need to join both of them into a third dataframe - Filled_HouseHouse(adress, number, zipcode, member1, member2, member3, member4) like

```
 adress 1, 28, 04030, Miki, null, null, null
 adress 2, 01, 25040, Sterling, Archer, null, null
```

In **Scala+Spark** I believe using map and group by could be the answer, but I did not figure the proper way out.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! For questions like this (probably home work?) it would be good to see that some efforts has been put into it trying to solve it. Please show the code you have so far and explain at what step you are stuck.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. By now, I got no failing code. I only have different hows to. The main one is 'val peopleGrouped = people.groupBy("adress")' 'peopleGrouped.foreach { row =>' and select position in the new dataframe. Here I have the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```
val peopleUnified = people.groupBy("address").agg(collect_list("name")
```

I got

```
adress 1, Miki
adress 2, [Sterling, Archer]
```

So next step is splitting the created list and filling the member fields with the join